# Detach volume from server with OpenStack Python SDK

Tags: python, sdk, openstack

I'm using the Openstack Python SDK and can successfully use it to retrieve a volume by name, extract it's attachments (if any). But I'm unable to to detach it from the attached server.

As I dig through the API docs found at the [OpenStack Python SDK docs](http://developer.openstack.org/sdks/python/openstacksdk/users/index.html) I can find no facilities to **detach** the volume. Is this simply not available at this time? Or am I (hopefully) just missing something? Extensive searching has not yielded any useful answers (but lots of links referencing back to using the various older Python clients as libraries).

For context, here's how I'm finding the volume:

```
from openstack import connection
from openstack import profile
....
conn = connection.Connection(
    auth_url=osApi,
    profile=prof,
    username=osUsername,
    project_name=osTenant,
    password=osPassword)
....
volumes = list(conn.block_store.volumes(name=args.volume))
volume = volumes[0]
print(volume)
```

The output I get from that snippet above:

```
openstack.block_store.v2.volume.VolumeDetail(source_volid=None, os-volume-replication:driver_data=None, links=[{'rel': 'self', 'href': 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxx:8776/v2/f13fa6a3bbc442f385f023134efc67fa/volumes/5afccea2-b1c0-4619-8cd2-d9e29235f109'}, {'rel': 'bookmark', 'href': 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxx:8776/f13fa6a3bbc442f385f023134efc67fa/volumes/5afccea2-b1c0-4619-8cd2-d9e29235f109'}], os-vol-mig-status-attr:name_id=None, os-vol-host-attr:host=xxxxxxxxxxxxx@lvm#lvm, bootable=true, id=5afccea2-b1c0-4619-8cd2-d9e29235f109, size=3, availability_zone=nova, volume_type=None, os-vol-mig-status-attr:migstat=None, snapshot_id=None, metadata={'readonly': 'False', 'attached_mode': 'rw'}, status=in-use, os-vol-tenant-attr:tenant_id=f13fa6a3bbc442f385f023134efc67fa, os-volume-replication:extended_status=None, attachments=[{'attachment_id': 'e10a42a8-a222-43df-997c-00605c8412ac', 'host_name': None, 'volume_id': '5afccea2-b1c0-4619-8cd2-d9e29235f109', 'server_id': '8a2b30f5-4fed-448b-a12b-3a79699c3017', 'device': '/dev/vdb', 'id': '5afccea2-b1c0-4619-8cd2-d9e29235f109'}], replication_status=disabled, name=xxxxxxxxxxxx, created_at=2017-01-24T20:50:42.000000, consistencygroup_id=None, encrypted=False, description=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

A volume can only be disconnected from a server that is turned off.
I needed to detach the volume specified by the name. I used the following:

```
volume = conn.get_volume(volume_name)
if volume.attachments:
    server_id = volume.attachments[0].server_id
    server = conn.get_server(server_id)
    print(f'Shutdown server {server.name}')
    if server.status == 'ACTIVE':
        conn.compute.stop_server(server)
        while conn.get_server(server_id).status != 'SHUTOFF':
            print('.', end='')
            time.sleep(1)
        print()
    conn.detach_volume(server, volume)
    print(f'Volume {volume.name} detached')
```

Comment: It would be great if you could explain to the readers on how your code solves the OPs problem

Comment: Changed the answer